# Java 8 Stream with batch processing

Tags: java, java-8, batch-processing, java-stream

I have a large file that contains a list of items.

I would like to create a batch of items, make an HTTP request with this batch  (all of the items are needed as parameters in the HTTP request). I can do it very easily with a `for` loop, but as Java 8 lover, I want to try writing this with Java 8's Stream framework (and reap the benefits of lazy processing).

Example:

```
List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>(BATCH_SIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
  batch.add(data.get(i));
  if (batch.size() == BATCH_SIZE) process(batch);
}

if (batch.size() > 0) process(batch);
```

I want to do something a long the line of
`lazyFileStream.group(500).map(processBatch).collect(toList())`

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I can't quite figure out how to perform the grouping, sorry, but [Files#lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) will lazily read the contents of the file.

Comment: so you basically need an inverse of `flatMap` (+ an additional flatMap to collapse the streams again)? I don't think something like that exists as a convenient method in the standard library. Either you'll have to find a 3rd party lib or write your own based on spliterators and/or a collector emitting a stream of streams

Comment: Maybe you can combine `Stream.generate` with `reader::readLine` and `limit`, but the problem is that streams don't go well with Exceptions. Also, this is probably not parallelizable well. I think the `for` loop is still the best option.

Comment: I just added an example code. I don't think flatMap is the way to go. Suspecting that I might have to write a custom Spliterator

Comment: I'm coining the term "Stream abuse" for questions like this.

Comment: Why is it "abuse"? It fits perfectly into the concept of streaming, especially for lazy streams. Basically, this requires a "groupBy", which I don't see a clear way of writing in Java 8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note! *This solution reads the whole file before running the forEach.*

You could do it with [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), a library that extends Java 8 streams for single-threaded, sequential stream use-cases:

```
Seq.seq(lazyFileStream)              // Seq<String>
   .zipWithIndex()                   // Seq<Tuple2<String, Long>>
   .groupBy(tuple -> tuple.v2 / 500) // Map<Long, List<String>>
   .forEach((index, batch) -> {
       process(batch);
   });
```

Behind the scenes, `zipWithIndex()` is just:

```
static <T> Seq<Tuple2<T, Long>> zipWithIndex(Stream<T> stream) {
    final Iterator<T> it = stream.iterator();

    class ZipWithIndex implements Iterator<Tuple2<T, Long>> {
        long index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return it.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple2<T, Long> next() {
            return tuple(it.next(), index++);
        }
    }

    return seq(new ZipWithIndex());
}
```

... whereas `groupBy()` is API convenience for:

```
default <K> Map<K, List<T>> groupBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier) {
    return collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier));
}
```

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)

Comment: Wow. This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Our system normally process data streams in sequence so this would be a good fit to move to Java 8.

Comment: Note that this solution unnecessarily stores the whole input stream to the intermediate `Map` (unlike, for example, Ben Manes solution)

Comment: Indeed, determining the end of the first batch, initializes the whole stream and buffers it internally.

Answer (score 160):

For completeness, here is a [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#partition-java.util.Iterator-int-) solution.

```
Iterators.partition(stream.iterator(), batchSize).forEachRemaining(this::process);
```

In the question the collection is available so a stream isn't needed and it can be written as,

```
Iterables.partition(data, batchSize).forEach(this::process);
```

Comment: `Lists.partition` is another variation that I should have mentioned.

Comment: this is lazy, right? it won't call the entire `Stream` to memory before processing the relevant batch

Comment: @orirab yes. It is lazy between batches, as in it will consume `batchSize` elements per iteration.

Answer (score 78):

Pure Java-8 implementation is also possible:

```
int BATCH = 500;
IntStream.range(0, (data.size()+BATCH-1)/BATCH)
         .mapToObj(i -> data.subList(i*BATCH, Math.min(data.size(), (i+1)*BATCH)))
         .forEach(batch -> process(batch));
```

Note that unlike JOOl it can work nicely in parallel (provided that your `data` is a random access list).

Comment: what if your data is actually a stream? (lets say lines in a file, or even from the network).

Comment: @OmryYadan, the question was about having input from the `List` (see `data.size()`, `data.get()` in the question). I'm answering the question asked. If you have another question, ask it instead (though I think the stream question was also already asked).

Comment: How to process the batches in parallel ?

Answer (score 52):

**Pure Java 8 solution**:

We can create a custom collector to do this elegantly, which takes in a `batch size` and a `Consumer` to process each batch:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;


/**
 * Collects elements in the stream and calls the supplied batch processor
 * after the configured batch size is reached.
 *
 * In case of a parallel stream, the batch processor may be called with
 * elements less than the batch size.
 *
 * The elements are not kept in memory, and the final result will be an
 * empty list.
 *
 * @param <T> Type of the elements being collected
 */
class BatchCollector<T> implements Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> {

    private final int batchSize;
    private final Consumer<List<T>> batchProcessor;


    /**
     * Constructs the batch collector
     *
     * @param batchSize the batch size after which the batchProcessor should be called
     * @param batchProcessor the batch processor which accepts batches of records to process
     */
    BatchCollector(int batchSize, Consumer<List<T>> batchProcessor) {
        batchProcessor = requireNonNull(batchProcessor);

        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.batchProcessor = batchProcessor;
    }

    public Supplier<List<T>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return (ts, t) -> {
            ts.add(t);
            if (ts.size() >= batchSize) {
                batchProcessor.accept(ts);
                ts.clear();
            }
        };
    }

    public BinaryOperator<List<T>> combiner() {
        return (ts, ots) -> {
            // process each parallel list without checking for batch size
            // avoids adding all elements of one to another
            // can be modified if a strict batching mode is required
            batchProcessor.accept(ts);
            batchProcessor.accept(ots);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        };
    }

    public Function<List<T>, List<T>> finisher() {
        return ts -> {
            batchProcessor.accept(ts);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        };
    }

    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

Optionally then create a helper utility class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public class StreamUtils {

    /**
     * Creates a new batch collector
     * @param batchSize the batch size after which the batchProcessor should be called
     * @param batchProcessor the batch processor which accepts batches of records to process
     * @param <T> the type of elements being processed
     * @return a batch collector instance
     */
    public static <T> Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> batchCollector(int batchSize, Consumer<List<T>> batchProcessor) {
        return new BatchCollector<T>(batchSize, batchProcessor);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();

int batchSize = 3;
Consumer<List<Integer>> batchProcessor = xs -> output.addAll(xs);

input.stream()
     .collect(StreamUtils.batchCollector(batchSize, batchProcessor));
```

I've posted my code on GitHub as well, if anyone wants to take a look:

[Link to Github](https://github.com/rovats/java-utils#batch-collector)

Comment: This is a good solution, unless you can't fit all the elements from your stream into the memory. Also it will not work on endless streams - collect method is terminal, which means that rather than producing stream of batches it will wait until the stream completes, and then process the result in batches.

Comment: @AlexAckerman an infinite stream will mean the finisher never gets called, but the accumulator will still be called so items will still be processed.  Also, it only requires the batch size of items to be in memory at any one time.

Comment: @Solubris, you are right! My bad, thanks for pointing this out - I won't delete the comment for the reference, if someone has the same idea of how the collect method works.

Comment: The list sent to the consumer should be copied to make it modification safe, eg: batchProcessor.accept(copyOf(ts))

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a custom Spliterator for scenarios like this.  It will fill lists of a given size from the input Stream.  The advantage of this approach is that it will perform lazy processing, and it will work with other stream functions.

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> batches(Stream<T> stream, int batchSize) {
    return batchSize <= 0
        ? Stream.of(stream.collect(Collectors.toList()))
        : StreamSupport.stream(new BatchSpliterator<>(stream.spliterator(), batchSize), stream.isParallel());
}

private static class BatchSpliterator<E> implements Spliterator<List<E>> {

    private final Spliterator<E> base;
    private final int batchSize;

    public BatchSpliterator(Spliterator<E> base, int batchSize) {
        this.base = base;
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<E>> action) {
        final List<E> batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
        for (int i=0; i < batchSize && base.tryAdvance(batch::add); i++)
            ;
        if (batch.isEmpty())
            return false;
        action.accept(batch);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<List<E>> trySplit() {
        if (base.estimateSize() <= batchSize)
            return null;
        final Spliterator<E> splitBase = this.base.trySplit();
        return splitBase == null ? null
                : new BatchSpliterator<>(splitBase, batchSize);
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        final double baseSize = base.estimateSize();
        return baseSize == 0 ? 0
                : (long) Math.ceil(baseSize / (double) batchSize);
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return base.characteristics();
    }

}
```

Comment: really helpful. If someone wants to batch on some custom criteria (for example size of collection in bytes), then you can delegate your custom predicate and use it in for-loop as a condition (imho while loop will be more readable then)

Comment: I'm not sure that implementation is correct. For instance, if the base stream is `SUBSIZED` the splits returned from `trySplit` can have more items than than before the split (if the split happens in the middle of the batch).

Comment: @Malt if my understanding of `Spliterators` is correct, then `trySplit` should always partition the data into two roughly equal parts so the result should never be larger than the original?

Comment: @BruceHamilton Unfortunately, according to the docs the parts can't be **roughly** equal. They **must** be equal: `if this Spliterator is SUBSIZED, then estimateSize() for this spliterator before splitting must be equal to the sum of estimateSize() for this and the returned Spliterator after splitting.`

Comment: Yes, that is consistent with my understanding of Spliterator splitting.  However, I am having a hard time understanding how "the splits returned from trySplit can have more items than than before the split", could you elaborate on what you mean there?

Answer (score 20):

We had a similar problem to solve. We wanted to take a stream that was larger than system memory (iterating through all objects in a database) and randomise the order as best as possible - we thought it would be ok to buffer 10,000 items and randomise them.

The target was a function which took in a stream.

Of the solutions proposed here, there seem to be a range of options:

- Use various non-java 8 additional libraries
- Start with something that's not a stream - e.g. a random access list
- Have a stream which can be split easily in a spliterator

Our instinct was originally to use a custom collector, but this meant dropping out of streaming. The custom collector solution above is very good and we nearly used it.

Here's a solution which cheats by using the fact that `Stream`s can give you an `Iterator` which you can use as *an escape hatch* to let you do something extra that streams don't support. The `Iterator` is converted back to a stream using another bit of Java 8 `StreamSupport` sorcery.

```
/**
 * An iterator which returns batches of items taken from another iterator
 */
public class BatchingIterator<T> implements Iterator<List<T>> {
    /**
     * Given a stream, convert it to a stream of batches no greater than the
     * batchSize.
     * @param originalStream to convert
     * @param batchSize maximum size of a batch
     * @param <T> type of items in the stream
     * @return a stream of batches taken sequentially from the original stream
     */
    public static <T> Stream<List<T>> batchedStreamOf(Stream<T> originalStream, int batchSize) {
        return asStream(new BatchingIterator<>(originalStream.iterator(), batchSize));
    }

    private static <T> Stream<T> asStream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(
            Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator,ORDERED),
            false);
    }

    private int batchSize;
    private List<T> currentBatch;
    private Iterator<T> sourceIterator;

    public BatchingIterator(Iterator<T> sourceIterator, int batchSize) {
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
        this.sourceIterator = sourceIterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        prepareNextBatch();
        return currentBatch!=null && !currentBatch.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> next() {
        return currentBatch;
    }

    private void prepareNextBatch() {
        currentBatch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
        while (sourceIterator.hasNext() && currentBatch.size() < batchSize) {
            currentBatch.add(sourceIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

A simple example of using this would look like this:

```
@Test
public void getsBatches() {
    BatchingIterator.batchedStreamOf(Stream.of("A","B","C","D","E","F"), 3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The above prints

```
[A, B, C]
[D, E, F]
```

For our use case, we wanted to shuffle the batches and then keep them as a stream - it looked like this:

```
@Test
public void howScramblingCouldBeDone() {
    BatchingIterator.batchedStreamOf(Stream.of("A","B","C","D","E","F"), 3)
        // the lambda in the map expression sucks a bit because Collections.shuffle acts on the list, rather than returning a shuffled one
        .map(list -> {
            Collections.shuffle(list); return list; })
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This outputs something like (it's randomised, so different every time)

```
A
C
B
E
D
F
```

The secret sauce here is that there's always a stream, so you can either operate on a stream of batches, or do something to each batch and then `flatMap` it back to a stream. Even better, all of the above only runs as the final `forEach` or `collect` or other terminating expressions *PULL* the data through the stream.

It turns out that `iterator` is a special type of *terminating operation* on a stream and does not cause the whole stream to run and come into memory! Thanks to the Java 8 guys for a brilliant design!

Comment: And it's very good that you fully iterate over each batch when it's collected and persist to a `List`—you can't defer iteration of the within-batch elements because the consumer may want to skip an entire batch, and if you didn't consume the elements then they wouldn't be skipping very far. (I have implemented one of these in C#, though it was substantially easier.)

Comment: this is one of the best solutions here.  totally underrated.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava):

RxJava v3:

```
int batchSize = 50;
List<Table> tables = new ArrayList<>();
Observable.fromIterable(_someStream_)
        .buffer(batchSize)
        .map(batch -> process(batch))
        .blockingSubscribe(tables::addAll, t -> Log.warning("Error", t));
```

Previous version:

```
Observable.from(data).buffer(BATCH_SIZE).forEach((batch) -> process(batch));
```

or

```
Observable.from(lazyFileStream).buffer(500).map((batch) -> process(batch)).toList();
```

or

```
Observable.from(lazyFileStream).buffer(500).map(MyClass::process).toList();
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also take a look at [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react), I am the author of this library. It implements the jOOλ interface (and by extension JDK 8 Streams), but unlike JDK 8 Parallel Streams it has a focus on Asynchronous operations (such as potentially blocking Async I/O calls). JDK Parallel Streams, by contrast focus on data parallelism for CPU bound operations. It works by managing aggregates of Future based tasks under the hood, but presents a standard extended Stream API to end users.

This sample code may help you get started

```
LazyFutureStream.parallelCommonBuilder()
                .react(data)
                .grouped(BATCH_SIZE)                  
                .map(this::process)
                .run();
```

There is a [tutorial on batching here](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/reactive-programming-with-java-8-and-simple-react-batching-and-chunking-ecac62ce8bec)

And a [more general Tutorial here](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/reactive-programming-with-java-8-and-simple-react-the-tutorial-3634f512eeb1)

To use your own Thread Pool (which is probably more appropriate for blocking I/O), you could start processing with

```
     LazyReact reactor = new LazyReact(40);

     reactor.react(data)
            .grouped(BATCH_SIZE)                  
            .map(this::process)
            .run();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Pure Java 8 example that works with parallel streams as well.**

How to use:

```
Stream<Integer> integerStream = IntStream.range(0, 45).parallel().boxed();
CsStreamUtil.processInBatch(integerStream, 10, batch -> System.out.println("Batch: " + batch));
```

The method declaration and implementation:

```
public static <ElementType> void processInBatch(Stream<ElementType> stream, int batchSize, Consumer<Collection<ElementType>> batchProcessor)
{
    List<ElementType> newBatch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);

    stream.forEach(element -> {
        List<ElementType> fullBatch;

        synchronized (newBatch)
        {
            if (newBatch.size() < batchSize)
            {
                newBatch.add(element);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                fullBatch = new ArrayList<>(newBatch);
                newBatch.clear();
                newBatch.add(element);
            }
        }

        batchProcessor.accept(fullBatch);
    });

    if (newBatch.size() > 0)
        batchProcessor.accept(new ArrayList<>(newBatch));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be easily done using
[Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/):

```
Flux.fromStream(fileReader.lines().onClose(() -> safeClose(fileReader)))
            .map(line -> someProcessingOfSingleLine(line))
            .buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
            .subscribe(apiService::makeHttpRequest);
```

Answer (score 4):

In all fairness, take a look at the elegant [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/) solution:

```
Stream.ofAll(data).grouped(BATCH_SIZE).forEach(this::process);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use apache.commons :

```
ListUtils.partition(ListOfLines, 500).stream()
                .map(partition -> processBatch(partition)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The partitioning part is done un-lazily but after the list is partitioned you get the benefits of working with streams (e.g. use parallel streams, add filters, etc.).
Other answers suggested more elaborate solutions but sometimes readability and maintainability are more important (and sometimes they are not :-) )

Comment: Not sure who downvoted but would be nice to understand why.. 
I gave an answer that supplemented the other answers for people not able to use Guava

Comment: You're processing a list here, not a stream.

Comment: @Drakemor I'm processing a stream of sub-lists. notice the stream() function call

Comment: But first you turn it into a list of sub-lists, which won't work correctly for *true* streamed data. Here is the reference to partition:  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition-java.util.List-int-

Comment: @Drakemor you are correct but OP wanted to use Java streams and not write reactive code which I think is what you mean when you say "true streaming".
In Java, stream() is used as a way to work functionally on collections and not as a mechanism. it is not the same as Stream in Javascript for instance

Comment: No, OP says "reap the benefits of lazy processing", and by putting the entire stream into the memory to create list of it, and turn it back into stream is not lazy processing. It's lazy programming.

Comment: @Drakemor ok you have a point here but still, some of the processing will be lazy. just not the part of separating into chunks. no need to be snappy... writing less code is not "lazy programming" it is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Sorry about the "snappyness" - this wasn't necessary. However I believe that the statement is still not true - getting entire thing into memory means that you no longer get any benefit from streaming, you just add overhead of splitting it to smaller chunks that get processed exactly as they would without splitting. Less code would be just ListOfLines.stream().map(...).collect(...).

Comment: TBH I don't fully get your argument but I guess we can agree to disagree.
I've edited my answer to reflect our conversation here. Thanks for the discussion

Answer (score 1):

Simple example using Spliterator

```
    // read file into stream, try-with-resources
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        //skip header
        Spliterator<String> split = stream.skip(1).spliterator();
        Chunker<String> chunker = new Chunker<String>();
        while(true) {              
            boolean more = split.tryAdvance(chunker::doSomething);
            if (!more) {
                break;
            }
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class Chunker<T> {
    int ct = 0;
    public void doSomething(T line) {
        System.out.println(ct++ + " " + line.toString());
        if (ct % 100 == 0) {
            System.out.println("====================chunk=====================");               
        }           
    }       
}
```

Bruce's answer is more comprehensive, but I was looking for something quick and dirty to process a bunch of files.

Answer (score 1):

this is a pure java solution that's evaluated lazily.

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> partition(Stream<T> stream, int batchSize){
    List<List<T>> currentBatch = new ArrayList<List<T>>(); //just to make it mutable 
    currentBatch.add(new ArrayList<T>(batchSize));
    return Stream.concat(stream
      .sequential()                   
      .map(new Function<T, List<T>>(){
          public List<T> apply(T t){
              currentBatch.get(0).add(t);
              return currentBatch.get(0).size() == batchSize ? currentBatch.set(0,new ArrayList<>(batchSize)): null;
            }
      }), Stream.generate(()->currentBatch.get(0).isEmpty()?null:currentBatch.get(0))
                .limit(1)
    ).filter(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Java 8` and `com.google.common.collect.Lists`, you can do something like:

```
public class BatchProcessingUtil {
    public static <T,U> List<U> process(List<T> data, int batchSize, Function<List<T>, List<U>> processFunction) {
        List<List<T>> batches = Lists.partition(data, batchSize);
        return batches.stream()
                .map(processFunction) // Send each batch to the process function
                .flatMap(Collection::stream) // flat results to gather them in 1 stream
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

In here `T` is the type of the items in the input list and `U` the type of the items in the output list

And You can use it like this:

```
List<String> userKeys = [... list of user keys]
List<Users> users = BatchProcessingUtil.process(
    userKeys,
    10, // Batch Size
    partialKeys -> service.getUsers(partialKeys)
);
```