# Java8 Stream batch processing to avoid OutOfMemory

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-8, java-stream

I'm having something like:

```
    List<Data> dataList = stepts.stream()
        .flatMap(step -> step.getPartialDataList().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So I'm combining into **dataList** multiple lists from every step.

My problem is that dataList might run into **OutOfMemoryError**.
Any suggestions on how I can batch the dataList and save the batches into db?

My primitive idea is to:

```
    for (Step step : steps) {
        List<Data> partialDataList = step.getPartialDataList();

        if (dataList.size() + partialDataList.size() <= MAXIMUM_SIZE) {
            dataList.addAll(partialDataList);
        } else {
            saveIntoDb(dataList);
            dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

PS: I know there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641383/java-8-stream-with-batch-processing) post, but the difference is that I might not be able to store whole data in memory.

LE: **getPartialDataList** metod is more like **createPartialDataList()**

Comment: are you performing any other operations on the data before saving the batches to the DB?

Comment: _might_? have you _tried_?

Comment: What could be relevant to the question further would be, what data size are we talking here for the `List<Data>`? How is `getPartialDataList` implemented? Does it keep a cursor over reads from the data?

Comment: @vphilipnyc no, just saving it

Comment: @Eugene, might, yes.  I'm trying to figure out all corner cases from a prod env.

Comment: @Naman, I'm using Hibernate. The thing I'm worried right now is the autogenerated id (mysql seq). getPartialList just creates some inMemory objects

Comment: If you really are trying to to do that, why not simulate a load, track GC activity and see if you really need that?

Answer (score 5):

If your concern is `OutOfMemoryError` you probably shouldn't create additional intermediate data structures like lists or streams before saving to the database.

Since the `Step.getPartialDataList()` already returns `List<Data>` the data is already in the memory, unless you have your own `List` implementation.  You just need to use [JDBC batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786127/1602555):

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data VALUES (?, ?, ...)");
for (Step step : steps) {
    for (Data data : step.getPartialDataList()) {
        ps.setString(1, ...);
        ps.setString(2, ...);
        ...
        ps.addBatch();
    }   
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

There is no need to chunk into smaller batches prematurely with `dataList`. First see what your database and JDBC driver are supporting before doing premature optimizations.

Do note that for most databases the right way to insert large amount of data is an external utility and not JDBC e.g. [PostgreSQL has `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

Comment: Best case would have been to do a bulk insert with all data. But in a prod env there might be a small chance to get OutOfMemory.
On step.getPartialDataList() I will create data on the fly, maybe the naming here is not the best. But surrely the enitre data is not in memory

Comment: @UnguruBulan I'd argue this answer is still the right one for your use-case. You can't process less data at a time than the result of one `getPartialDataList()`

Comment: I want to process more data than the result of `getPartialDataList()`